# xslt:choose , how to define when condition

Tags: xml, xslt

I am learning XSLT and have written a code to convert XML from one form to another. I am facing an issue with the first `xsl:when` condition. The code is not picking the  condition and skips to the `xsl:otherwise` section. Could somebody please help me identify my mistake?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">

<FoodList>
<xsl:for-each select="Food/FoodItem">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="ItemType = 'Fruit'">
This is a fruit
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
This is a vegetable
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<FoodName>
<xsl:value-of select="ItemName"/>
</FoodName>
<FoodQuantity> 
<xsl:value-of select="ItemQuantity"/>
</FoodQuantity>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="ItemQuantity &gt; 10">
<ShipMessage>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">can be shipped </xsl:text>
</ShipMessage>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<ShipMessage>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">do not ship </xsl:text>
</ShipMessage>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>    
<FoodPrice>
<xsl:value-of select="ItemPrice"/>
</FoodPrice>
</xsl:for-each>
</FoodList>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My input file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Food>
<FoodItem>
<ItemType>  Fruit </ItemType>
<ItemName> Apple  </ItemName>
<ItemQuantity> 5 </ItemQuantity>
<ItemPrice> 300 </ItemPrice>
</FoodItem>
<FoodItem>
<ItemName> Tomato  </ItemName>
<ItemType>  Vegetable </ItemType>
<ItemQuantity> 5 </ItemQuantity>
<ItemPrice> 10 </ItemPrice>
</FoodItem>
<FoodItem>

<ItemName> Mango  </ItemName>
<ItemType>  Fruit </ItemType>
<ItemQuantity> 15 </ItemQuantity>
<ItemPrice> 300 </ItemPrice>
</FoodItem>
</Food>
```

The output I get is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><FoodList>
This is a vegetable
<FoodName> Apple  </FoodName><FoodQuantity> 5 </FoodQuantity><ShipMessage>do not ship </ShipMessage><FoodPrice> 300 </FoodPrice>
This is a vegetable
<FoodName> Tomato  </FoodName><FoodQuantity> 5 </FoodQuantity><ShipMessage>do not ship </ShipMessage><FoodPrice> 10 </FoodPrice>
This is a vegetable
<FoodName> Mango  </FoodName><FoodQuantity> 15 </FoodQuantity><ShipMessage>can be shipped </ShipMessage><FoodPrice> 300 </FoodPrice>
```

Comment: Tried in xalan and saxon, result is the same: This is a fruit, then This is a vegetable, then This is a fruit. Which xslt processor do you use?

Comment: @RudolfYurgenson i tried to run this directly on w3schools website. Moreover, i am working on an integration tool, where in I used this XSLT in my 'ApplyXSLT' activity and got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ItemType` value is not `"Fruit"`, it is `"  Fruit  "`. The whitespace is significant. If you want to match ignoring the whitespace, use

```
test="normalize-space(ItemType) = "Fruit"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <FoodList>
<xsl:for-each select="Food/FoodItem">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="normalize-space(ItemType) = 'Fruit'">
This is a fruit
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
This is a vegetable
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<FoodName>
<xsl:value-of select="ItemName"/>
</FoodName>
<FoodQuantity> 
<xsl:value-of select="ItemQuantity"/>
</FoodQuantity>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="ItemQuantity &gt; 10">
<ShipMessage>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">can be shipped </xsl:text>
</ShipMessage>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<ShipMessage>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">do not ship </xsl:text>
</ShipMessage>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>    
<FoodPrice>
<xsl:value-of select="ItemPrice"/>
</FoodPrice>
</xsl:for-each>
</FoodList>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is a fruit
<FoodName> Apple  </FoodName><FoodQuantity> 5 </FoodQuantity><ShipMessage>do not ship </ShipMessage><FoodPrice> 300 </FoodPrice>
This is a vegetable
<FoodName> Tomato  </FoodName><FoodQuantity> 5 </FoodQuantity><ShipMessage>do not ship </ShipMessage><FoodPrice> 10 </FoodPrice>
This is a fruit
<FoodName> Mango  </FoodName><FoodQuantity> 15 </FoodQuantity><ShipMessage>can be shipped </ShipMessage><FoodPrice> 300 </FoodPrice></FoodList>